# Html Helper CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Fatal error:

> Call to a member function charset() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\controllers\test_controller.php on line 10

PHP Controller Code:

```
<?php
class TestsController extends AppController
  {
      var $name="Tests";
      var $helpers = array('Html');
      var $uses=array();
# demo action to check wheather html helper is working or not
      function index()
       {     echo "111111111";
              echo $this->Html->charset();
              echo "22222222222"; 
       }
   }
?>
```

I am getting the above error while hitting the url: `http://localhost/demo/tests`

I am using CakePHP 2.0 ALPHA (latest version).

Please let me know what is the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Following CakePHP's MVC convention, you should by using behaviors in models, components in controllers and helpers in views. You are currently trying to use a helper in a controller, which won't work. I suggest you go back and have another look at [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/), but for something like `HtmlHelper::charset()` you really want to be calling that once in the `<head>` tag of your layout (which is also part of the view layer):

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html?highlight=layout#layouts

Comment: `TestsController` it's a controller, not a component :)